# Send HTML message with links using Mailgun

Tags: java, mailgun

I am trying to send and HTML based message which includes a link using mailgun in Java. The issue is that the HTML code is displayed as is in the email client and it does not render it as HTML formatted content.

I am refering to the example given in this URL -

https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#sending-via-api

```
Client client = Client.create();
       client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("api",
                       "key-***"));
       WebResource webResource =
               client.resource("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox***.mailgun.org/" +                            "messages");
       FormDataMultiPart form = new FormDataMultiPart();
       form.field("from", "Admin <admin@test.com>");
       form.field("to", "User <user123@gmail.com>");
       form.field("subject", "Hello User");
       form.field("text", "Testing some Mailgun awesomness! <BR> this should be in new line &lt;BR&gt;this shoud aso be be new line");
       return webResource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(ClientResponse.class, form);
```

Can anybody having experience with mailgun help me. I need to send email with clickable links in it (anchor tags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the api documentation try the following:

```
 form.field('html','<html><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">HTML version of the body</a></html>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and ended up creating a [small library](https://github.com/sargue/mailgun) to send emails throw Mailgun easily. And also I've tried to make it easy to send basic HTML emails.

Your example would translate to something like this:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
    .domain("sandbox***.mailgun.org")
    .apiKey("key-***")
    .from("Admin", "admin@test.com");

MailBuilder.using(configuration)
    .to("User", "user123@gmail.com")
    .subject("Hello User")
    .text("I suggest you also include a text-only version of your content")
    .html("Testing some Mailgun awesomness! <BR> this should be in new line" + 
          " &lt;BR&gt;this shoud aso be be new line!")
    .build()
    .send();
```

For simple HTML messages I suggest you take a look at the `MailContent` helper class on the project.